# The requested package /product-community-edition could not be found in any version

Tags: magento2, upgrade, magento-2.0, magento-2.0.4

I try to do the Magento 2 update from 2.0.2 to 2.0.7 using the command.

```
composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.0.4 --no-update
composer update
rm -rf var/di var/generation
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

But after the first 2 commands I get the message:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - The requested package /product-community-edition could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see <https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability> for more details.
```

Where does the package product-community-edition come from? Do I need to upload it or make any connection?

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that you originally installed Magento 2 via the GIT repository.

Thus you need to run the following before the commands you listed:

```
git pull origin 2.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Not that this was necessarily your issue, but in case others find this as I did. I found the same error was caused by executing `composer update` in the wrong directory (/bin) :/.

Comment: what would be the correct /bin?

Comment: The root (i.e. the folder before /bin) is the correct one.